# I need help identifying this 10K 4Pin potentiometer

Tags: identification, potentiometer

This blue Potentiometer is from a Numark NV DJ Controller.
[image]
It has 10K, 4Pins and I need to replace multiple of them, since they're getting less accurate. You can get them for 12€ the piece on a single website, which is overpriced. I've found similar Potis on AliExpress, but they all don't have the extended shaft. Any help is appreciated. I'm thankful for any link, where I can get them for cheap!
~djRimzi

EDIT: Picture of the Pins:

[image]

Comment: You may find a good match from ALPS.

Comment: `get them for cheap` ... you'll be back to `they're getting less accurate` in no time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an obsolete Bourns Pot.  10k. the shafts are plastic now. But you need to define the bottom pins , stereo, linear or log etc 1/4" 26 or 32 tpi
Most are metric now

You can find an equiv on D-K site or Mouser https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/PTV112-4220A-B103?qs=h2IHEVivlqBiDxqtaFbOxg%3D%3D    Compare dimensions on datasheet with yours

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the pins. Hopefully it can help you! Also could you post the link of the site pls? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: near all the dimensions as well as the thread size if used